How to make a custom crash logger for react native?
How do I go about creating a custom error logger that logs the messages in a file when my react native app is running on my device and crashes unexpectedly. Can't use Crashlytics, how do I do so??
I thought of using try catch and whenever an error is caught it sends the message to a file.

It's a good idea to clearify why you can not use Crashlytics.
